# Xamarin.ios not running in visual studio on mac

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2010, xcode6

When trying to run the ios version of the app on the built in Generic simulator i get the following error and program stops

```
error MT0026: Could not parse the command line argument '-sdk': Version string portion 
was too short or too long.
Parameter name: input
```

I have xcode latest installed and i see this error

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve thanks xcode is latest 14.3 There is no list of ios simulators in VS studio.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve no matter what i do the simulators do not show.

Answer (score 1):

Please be informed that `XCode 14.3` support hasn't been released yet and it is suggested that you use `Xcode 14.2`. If you have updated to the latest `Xcode 14.3` and want to go back to the previous version: `Xcode 14.2`,you can download `Xcode 14.2` from [the downloads page](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/) in the Apple Developer Portal.

After successfully installing `Xcode 14.2`. You may open Xcode and go to **Xcode**->**Preferences**->**Location**->**Command Line Tools** to `XCode 14.2`. And then restart the Visual Studio for mac to see it works.

For more details, you can refer to [Xcode 14.3 Support for Xamarin, .NET 6/7 and MAUI #17561](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/17561).

Comment: I have not heard from you for a while. Please let me know if there is anything that I can help here.